# Knockout JS: mapping.fromJS stripping out observable attributes of object when added

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coffeescript

I have the following ko.mapping and an object (coffeescript):

```
form_fields = ko.mapping.fromJS []

obj =
  name: ko.observable 'some_name'
  type: ko.observable 'some_type'
  avail_values: ko.observableArray some_array
  vals: ko.observableArray some_other_array_of_observables
```

I've verified that `obj` is being populated as expected by knockout observable functions.  If I call `obj.name()` I get the expected value back, for example.

However, when I do `form_fields.push obj` OR `ko.mapping.fromJS [obj], form_fields`, `form_fields` is populated with an empty object.  The object exists within the array, but it has no attributes at all.

Here's the resulting array in the chrome dev tools:

[image: Dev tools object]

Do I need to do something else to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you make a js fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ko.mapping.fromJS [obj], {}, form_fields
```

The empty object in the middle is the [mapping rules](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#advanced_usage), a parameter which is required when you specify a mapping target.